# iOS Autolayout - Position view correctly below translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar, autolayout

In my storyboard, I have a `UIImageView` that I'd like to place at a fixed distance below a translucent navigation bar. I have the simulated top bar for the view controller set to the translucent bar, and the constraint I have now says "Top Space to Superview Equals 52," 8 points below the bar.

However, when the view rotates to landscape, the navigation bar shrinks to 34 points, and the image view is still at 52 points like it was in portrait.

What constraint can I use in IB to place the image view at 8 points below the navigation bar no matter how tall the bar is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Select your `UIImageView` and control-drag to the Top Layout Guide to create a constraint. If you're not familiar with the Top Layout Guide, you can select it in the structure view on the left.

Answer (score 1):

As Nestor pointed out, you are setting the top spacing with top edge of the view and not the nearest neighbor which is the navigation bar. You should set the top spacing constraint with the Top Layout Guide in order to make it fixed whatever the size class and orientations are.

To do so, from the document outline view, hold ctrl click and drag a line from the `UIImageView` to the `Top Layout Guide` and select `Vertical Spacing` from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select both the imageView and the topBar in storyBoard. At the bottom right of the screen you'll see a button that looks like an H:

[image]

Select it and choose "Vertical Spacing". Set the contraint equal to 8 pixels, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to select the top bar though, maybe because it's just simulated metrics? I didn't actually add a navigation bar element to the view.

Comment: You should do it programmatically, I know that it seems a pain, but if you use VLF isn't that hard.

Comment: The question says "in IB".

Answer (score 0):

swift 4, iOS11+, SnapKit

```
imageView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
   maker.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(8)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the SnapKit?

Answer (score 0):

If you use old Xcode you will [can connect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide) `topLayoutGuide` or `bottomLayoutGuide` of your ViewController.
But now it way is deprecated. For applications for new operation systems, [you should use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/3553228-safearealayoutguide)  `safeAreaLayoutGuide` of a view.

IB does not support distinguish of operation systems, but you can create temporary constraint in IB and add a real constraint from a code:

[image]

After that add a code in some place of `viewDidLoad`:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
} else {
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```